# How to make a ROC with sklearn elastic net?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have:

r = numpy array of 6 features, i.e. shape ~10000 x 6

answer = binary numpy array (1 or 0) that I want to learn to predict, shape ~1000 x 1

I've done:

```
[datatrain, datatest, answertrain, answertest] = cross_validation.train_test_split(r,answer)
clf = linear_model.ElasticNet()
clf.fit(X=datatrain,y=answertrain) 
prediction = clf.predict(datatest)
```

How do I get thresholds for a ROC? I don't see an attribute for a decision function or prediction probabilities or anything.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`?

Comment: Yes that's what I normally use, and the arguments it requires are the true labels and the scores/probabilities. I don't know how to get the second argument from elastic net.

Comment: Elastic net is a regression model, so it can't predict the probability. If you want to evaluate the accuracy of Elastic net, you can use the coefficient of determination R ^ 2 of the prediction.

Comment: But I can get a prediction with clf.predict(datatest). So how come it can make a prediction, but can't give me scores or probabilities? Is there nothing equivalent to a decision function?

Comment: Regression and classification models are different. You can see more theoretical content.